# Android deep linking schema: match both http and https

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I want my app to open on `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com`.

This works:

```
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="http"/>

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="https"/>
```

Is it possible to catch both with one entry? I tried:

```
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="http*"/>
```

but this catches only the http link, not the https one.

So I know how I can handle bot variants, but want to use the most concise writing possible.

Comment: It is not possible i think

Comment: I am also think, it's not possible.

Comment: I don't think this field support regex, but you could try `android:scheme="https?"`

Comment: Also this could work: `<data android:host="www.example.com" android:path="/"/>  <data android:scheme="http"/>  <data android:scheme="https"/>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This seems to do the trick for me:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="www.mywebsite.com" />
    <data android:pathPrefix="/mypage.php" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: not working for me. It show me
 /build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED:
Install canceled by user]

Answer (score 4):

You can use seperate `<intent-filter>` for both

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:path="/"
            android:scheme="http"/>     
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:path="/"
            android:scheme="https"/>     
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid, I wanted to have the shortest (in terms of characters in my manifest) possibility.

Comment: sometimes you cannot avoid, except if you are going to change OS coding :)

Comment: I have added that but stilll my app is not uploading